# android: resource not found

Tags: android, resources

I just updated from android 2.1 to 3.0 and found many default andorid resources missing, such as:

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
```

What happened to then and any idea how to fix them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not exist anymore, most likely.  The Android folks advise against using their resources because of changes in the API -- now you know why  :)
I would keep a local copy from previous releases so that you can access them, were I you.  (something they also suggest)

Comment: Again, per their own Docs, that may change. You are using a "Private" source at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/android:ic_menu_help"
```

Comment: I am curious to know why this works. What's with that syntax?