# Problems with android icons in Menu

Tags: android, menu, icons

I have this menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/refresh" android:title="Actualizar" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_refresh"></item>
<item android:title="Sair" android:id="@+id/exit" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"></item></menu>
```

and i'm getting this error:

**Error: Resource is not public. (at 'icon' with value '@android:drawable/ic_menu_refresh').**

Why the resource is not public? I have this icon in other apps and worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's protected. In some API level, some icons are allowed to use, some are not. You can try `ic_menu_home` `ic_menu_preferences` `ic_menu_help`

Some links to refer:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/dabbe62aa1b54c13

[android: resource not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797480/android-resource-not-found)